# How to check for Platform Encryption

Tags: apex, platform-encryption

Does anybody know how to check if Platform Encryption is enabled in a given org? Ideally without using the metadata API.

I don't need to know if a user/permset has access to "View Encrypted Data", I simply have to change some functionality if data is Encrypted (no where clause on some standard fields, for example).

Can't find any docs to that effect... yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to find the perfect solution.

`sObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isEncrypted()`

That solved it. :)

Comment: Yep thats documented as well in the doc that I listed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm

Comment: isn't this a constrained answer as your would have to know that contact.name is encrypted in your target org?  

"isEncrypted - This value only appears in the results of a describeSObjects() call when it is true; otherwise, it is omitted from the results."

Comment: @BenjaminPirih I see your point here . Seb you may want to double check this return false in org where platform encryption is not enabled .This may cause null pointer else

Comment: That became the plan, once Ben made the remark above. Though a try-catch around the line (in a utility class) would solve both issues

Comment: I can now confirm that `sObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isEncrypted()` does not throw an exception when encryption is turned off, or not even activated.

Answer (score 4):

I assume there are couple of Objects that will have some Entry if the platform encryption is enabled .

The Two Objects that I would look are [TenantSecret](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_tenantsecret.htm) and TenantUsageEntitlement

```
system.debug('$$$'+[SELECT AmountUsed,EndDate FROM TenantUsageEntitlement]);
```

I have no access to org with Platform Encryption Enabled else I would verify this .I assume TenantSecret object appears only once Platform encryption is enabled

If you want at Object level to see Platform Encyrption is enabled check in describe Object for is encrypted boolean documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) .

Answer (score 0):

know ideally you didn't want to use metadata API but.. Could you attempt to create an encrypted field with the metadata api.

If this call fails it should return an error message that encryption is not available.  If the call succeeds then you need to rollback the creation via another call but you will know that the org feature is enabled.  Not pretty..

Comment: This is for an ISV package. Requesting access to the Metadata API is not something we're ready to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely check if encryption is enabled for a particular field, even if that field lives within an org that doesn't have Platform Encryption provisioned.

The only trickiness is that when Platform Encryption isn't provisioned onto an org, calling Apex Describe on an sObject won't return the IsEncrypted field as part of its result.

You can work around this by checking for both null and false in your Apex code.

Here's a short example of a Visualforce page that utilizes Apex to generate a list of every field associated with the Account sObject, and it's encryptability. You can do something similar in your code to branch based on whether encryption is available for a particular field.

```
<apex:page >
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = setupPage;

        function setupPage() {
            queryResult = sforce.connection.describeSObject("Account");

            if (queryResult.fields.length > 0) {
            var output = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < queryResult.fields.length; i++) {
                var field = queryResult.fields[i];
                output += field.name + " — " + "Encrypted: " + (field.encrypted ? "true" : "false") + "<br />";
            }

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
        }
    </script>

    <div id="output"></div>
</apex:page>
```

This would output something like this:

> Id — Encrypted: false
>
> IsDeleted — Encrypted: false
>
> MasterRecordId — Encrypted: false
>
> Name — Encrypted: true
>
> Type — Encrypted: false
>
> ParentId — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingStreet — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingCity — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingState — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingPostalCode — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingCountry — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingLatitude — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingLongitude — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingGeocodeAccuracy — Encrypted: false
>
> BillingAddress — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingStreet — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingCity — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingState — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingPostalCode — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingCountry — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingLatitude — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingLongitude — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingGeocodeAccuracy — Encrypted: false
>
> ShippingAddress — Encrypted: false
>
> Phone — Encrypted: false
>
> Fax — Encrypted: false
>
> AccountNumber — Encrypted: false
>
> Website — Encrypted: false
>
> PhotoUrl — Encrypted: false
>
> Sic — Encrypted: false
>
> Industry — Encrypted: false
>
> AnnualRevenue — Encrypted: false
>
> NumberOfEmployees — Encrypted: false
>
> Ownership — Encrypted: false
>
> TickerSymbol — Encrypted: false
>
> Description — Encrypted: false
>
> Rating — Encrypted: false
>
> Site — Encrypted: false
>
> OwnerId — Encrypted: false
>
> CreatedDate — Encrypted: false
>
> CreatedById — Encrypted: false
>
> LastModifiedDate — Encrypted: false
>
> LastModifiedById — Encrypted: false
>
> SystemModstamp — Encrypted: false
>
> LastActivityDate — Encrypted: false
>
> LastViewedDate — Encrypted: false
>
> LastReferencedDate — Encrypted: false
>
> Jigsaw — Encrypted: false
>
> JigsawCompanyId — Encrypted: false
>
> CleanStatus — Encrypted: false
>
> AccountSource — Encrypted: false
>
> DunsNumber — Encrypted: false
>
> Tradestyle — Encrypted: false
>
> NaicsCode — Encrypted: false
>
> NaicsDesc — Encrypted: false
>
> YearStarted — Encrypted: false
>
> SicDesc — Encrypted: false
>
> DandbCompanyId — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__CustomerPriority__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__SLA__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Active__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__NumberofLocations__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__UpsellOpportunity__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__SLASerialNumber__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__SLAExpirationDate__c — Encrypted: false
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_1__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_2__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_3__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_4__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_5__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_6__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_7__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_8__c — Encrypted: true
>
> BRHdjkSmZB__Encrypted_Text_9__c — Encrypted: true

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check "no where clause" is to use sObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isFilterAble().