# How can I test to see if a field is encrypted using Shield Platform Encryption?

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

If I encrypt fields with the Platform Shield Encryption, but still see the fields when I'm a different user how can I test to see if the encryption is working?

I understand it encrypts at rest so I created a new account after setting the fields I wanted to be encrypted.

Can all users in my org see the encrypted data? 
Is it only people that some how break into my org that will see encrypted data?

I just want to be able to test out how things look when using the shield platform encryption on certain objects or when doing SOQL/SOSL.

Comment: look at [How to check for Platform Encryption](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118215/how-to-check-for-platform-encryption) and [platform encryption at rest](http://santanuboral.blogspot.in/2017/12/platform-encryption-encryption-at-rest.html)

Comment: Ha!  Nice!  You found someone crazier than I am!  He actually did the "delete the key" thing! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other thing is the setup gives you insight about the statistics around how much data is encrypted. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_stats_gather.htm

The actual way is as Shane mentioned to destroy your key, this is something you should not do in your prod org but you can in a sandbox if you need to be convinced :)

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the approach I'm doing after speaking with my group, but I appreciate the workbench approach because I learned something new!    -- we might even consider the crazy key deleting approach on smaller sample :P

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

One quick way to do it is to look at the field in **[Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php?startUrl=%2Fselect.php)**.  You should see it listed as "encrypted: true".

If you're looking for a more definitive "prove-it-to-me" test, you could (**BACKUP and then**) delete the encryption key, though I'd be a little too timid to try that!  If you went that route, you wouldn't be able to see any of the values in the encrypted fields.  You could then restore the key from backup, and see everything just fine...but, again, there's no way I would try that!  Have a little faith in the Salesforce peoples!